# IronPdf - Signature Image is not rendered in digitally signed PDF

Tags: c#, digital-signature, ironpdf

I would like to generate a digitally signed pdf ***with a signature image*** using the [IronPdf](https://ironpdf.com/) library, but I am experiencing the following issue:

While the pdf is digitally signed, the signature's image does not seem to be rendering/appearing in the generated pdf.

The above code (that I am testing in a console app) is based on: https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/signing/ (3rd case)

```
// Step 1. Create a PDF
ChromePdfRenderer Renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
using PdfDocument doc = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Testing 2048 bit digital security</h1>");

// Step 2. Create a Signature.
// You may create a .pfx or .p12 PDF signing certificate using Adobe Acrobat Reader.
// Read: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/digital-ids.html
var Signature = new IronPdf.Signing.PdfSignature("ChristosAsvestopoulos.pfx", "123abc!");

// Step 3. Optional signing options and a handwritten Signature graphic
Signature.SigningContact = "support@ironsoftware.com";
Signature.SigningLocation = "Chicago, USA";
Signature.SigningReason = "To show how to sign a PDF";
Signature.LoadSignatureImageFromFile("handwriting.png");

//Step 4. Sign the PDF with the PdfSignature. Multiple signing certificates may be used
doc.SignPdfWithDigitalSignature(Signature);

//Step 5. The PDF is not signed until saved to file, steam or byte array.
doc.SaveAs("signed.pdf");
```

Notes:

The .pfx file was created following this: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/digital-ids.html

IronPdf version: 2022.8.7894

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

application's framework: .NET Core 3.1

For `handwriting.png` file I have also tried (without success) this: https://ironpdf.com/troubleshooting/digital-signatures/

Answer (score 2):

This is Vince from Iron Software.
This is a known issue regarding Signatures - Image in digital signatures not visible and has been confirmed by IronPDF's engineers. It has been logged to our development team.

I have linked this article to the development ticket, so we will reach out and notify you once this is resolved in a future update.

You can send a follow up to developers@ironsfotware.com with Ticket# 54677.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in IronPdf version [2023.3.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/2023.3.2).

```cs
ChromePdfRenderer renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
PdfDocument pdf = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>foo</h1>");

pdf.SaveAs("signed.pdf");

// Create PdfSignature object
var sig = new PdfSignature("IronSoftware.pfx", "123456");

// Add image
sig.SignatureImage = new PdfSignatureImage("IronSoftware.png", 0, new CropRectangle(0, 600, 100, 100));

// Sign and save PDF document
sig.SignPdfFile("signed.pdf");
```

Please visit [Digitally Sign a PDF Document](https://ironpdf.com/how-to/signing/) for more information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).